# Silent install application request routing using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to install Application Request Routing using below PowerShell script
"Start-Process 'C:\temp\ARRv3_0.exe' '/qn' -PassThru"
I'm able to install but getting dialog box at the end. I need to suppress that dialog box also.
Can anyone help me out..

Comment: What Dialog Box?

Comment: @bjoster Thanks for the reply..... 
Package is installed(dialog box will open with exit button) and manually i need to press exit button in the dialog box

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `/v/qn` then. `/v:...`will pass anything that follows onto the embedded MSI installer. The /qn is an msiexec switch indicating to run with no UI.

The "wierd" format is required because that is how the InstallShield command-line parser is programmed to function. Likely, they built it this way to ensure msiexec switches/properties will be unambiguous on the command-line and within scripts.

Comment: Same error coming... Any idea on this

Comment: Hmm, maybe installing arr through wepPi? (https://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/automating-arr-configuration/)

Comment: I tried with webpi also but getting error like cannot find .webpi.exe

Comment: But you have *installed* the Plattform Installer?

Comment: Yes I installed but after installation of Application  Request Routing(ARR) getting windows dialog box and I need to suppress this box also

Comment: I tested this this very second and the WebPi installs ARR without any dialog box: `PS C:\WEBPI> .\WebpiCmd.exe /Install /Products:'UrlRewrite2,ARRv3_0' /AcceptEULA /Log:c:/temp/Webpi.log`